Why doesn’t Neovim highlight or lint my arduino code?
I have kickstarter installed. I used Mason to install the arduino LSP implementation. The arduino CLI is installed along with the standard arduino IDE, clangd, and treesitter.
Im using a lilygo gsm 7000 arduino-based board, so I went over to their GitHub and pulled the an example code file to start working with.
After pasting it into Neovim I just have a solid white text: no color, no correction recommendations, etc.
Am I supposed to make additional changes to any files?

See How to debug my vimrc

Write the file with an appropriate file extension and re-open the file.

You have to set the filetype of the buffer to arduino (you can achieve that by running the :set ft=arduino command).
If you save the file with a .ino extension and reload it Neovim will set the filetype to arduino automatically (as @Heptite mentionned).

Thank you very much.

Thank for the feedback! Ifvthe answer solves your problem maybe could you accept it using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons.  It allow the question to rest :-)
